# merge excel sheets based on multiple (3) columns

Tags: excel, merge

I'm trying to help a non-technical customer merge two excel sheet together, but based on three common columns.

- One spreadsheet comes from my software and includes the last name, first name, PO#, and job id.
- The second comes from their timecard software and contains a column for last name, first name, PO#, and hours.
- Each employee can use multiple PO#s in a single week, meaning that the names and PO# can appear multiple times on both sheets but are unique when the three are used together.

I'm trying to find a method to combine the two sheets based on last name, first name, and PO#, to include a single row with job id and hours worked (last name, first name, PO#, job id, hours worked). `VLOOKUP()` seems to be based on a primary key column, and I've seen videos of people selling excel add-ins that will do this, but I'm trying to find a method without asking the customer to purchase something else.

I've also read up on the idea of merging the three columns into a single column and then using `VLOOKUP()`, but I'm not sure I can get this customer to understand that. Am I missing a simpler way to do this or is this harder than is seems?

Answer (score 0):

Create a concatenated field on both sheets that combine last name, first name and PO#. I would use a separator in the concatenation to avoid any parts of names messing up the process. Put this column at the beginning of the two tables (you can hide them afterwards). Then use a standard VLOOKUP match on the new concatenated field to do the matching.